# IBM SPSS 20: Rank and output a Matrix of Pearson's Correlations?

Tags: spss

I was given a data set with 1,000 variables and have been asked to run Pearson's correlations on the explanatory variables and a binary dependent variable. I generate the correlations using the following code:

```
correlations /variables = x1 to x500 with y
correlations /variables = x501 to x1000 with y
```

The resulting output is a table which appears un-sortable in SPSS or other software (e.g. Excel)

```
x1 Pearson Correlation
   p-value
   N
-----------------------
x2 Pearson Correlation
   p-value
   N
-----------------------
         .
         .
         .
-----------------------
xi Pearson Correlation
   p-value
   N
-----------------------
```

I want to be able to rank the variables according to Pearson's Correlation and then p-value. Does SPSS have the capability to save the Variable Name, Pearson's Correlation value and p-Value as a table, and then rank them?

I am too used to Stata and R and could not notice anything in the manual. Would a workaround be to run univariate regression models with only one dependent variable 1,000 times and try saving those coefficients?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pivot the statistics into the columns in the output table, which would give you a sortable arrangement.  Try it with a few variables to see how this works.  You double click the table to activate it and then Use Pivot > Pivoting Trays to open the controls for pivoting.

To do this for your real data, you will want to capture the table using OMS, creating a new dataset, which you can then sort or do other data manipulation operations.  When you create your OMS command, you will want to tell it to pivot the table so that the dataset arrangement is convenient.

Bear in mind that fishing for the highest correlations is likely to give you an overly optimistic view of the predictive power of the top variables.

The NAIVEBAYES procedure (Statistics Server) might be another approach to consider.  Check the Command Syntax Reference for details.